# Make a base route filter with hapijs

Tags: node.js, url, routes, hapi.js, base-url

i'm new to nodejs and i'm making an api with hapijs to handle some functionalities from mi site, i want to be able to make a base url like api/* and make all others url that start with api/ pass throug some validations but only do that once, this is what i have so far:

```
server.route([
            {
                method: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
                path: "/api/*",
                handler: function(request, reply){
                    is_authorized = auth(request.raw.req.headers['Authorization']);
                    if(!is_authorized){
                        reply(response.generate_json(null, 'no autorizado', 'UNAUTHORIZED')).code(401);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

but it doesn't work, when i call any other url like api/sockets/whatever it just passes even if it's not authorized.... is there any way i can achive this in hapijs??

Comment: Have you looked at the [tutorial on Authentication](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth?lang=en_US)? It describes how to set up a single function that all routes can use for authentication.

Comment: yep i did after i posted this.... by creating an auth schema and an auth strategy you can set up authentication to all the routes you want and not authenticate those you dont.... thanks for the reply!

Comment: awesome! you should post an answer here and accept it!

Comment: Will do as soon as I get a chance, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use on prehandler hook

```
server.ext('onPreHandler', (request, reply) => {
if(request.path.startsWith("/api/"))
{
    is_authorized = auth(request.raw.req.headers['Authorization']);
    if(!is_authorized)
    {
        reply(response.generate_json(null, 'no autorizado', 'UNAUTHORIZED')).code(401);
    }
    else
    {
      return reply.continue();
    }
}
else
{
return reply.continue();
}
});
```

if you need any further info.happy to help